# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OUTPUT_ARRAY'

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I'm stuck with this error and really don't know how to fix it. Maybe i'm passing array in improper way?

This is main sql file.

```
DECLARE
  v_array_length NUMBER := &v_array_length;
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    TYPE number_array_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER(6, 2) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    v_array NUMBER_ARRAY_TYPE;
  BEGIN
    --Isvediams
    IOPACKAGE.OUTPUT_MESSAGE('Original array:');
    --Sugeneruoja atsitiktinius array elementus is intervalo [1, 1000]
    FOR i IN 1..v_array_length LOOP
            v_array(i) := SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 1000);
          END LOOP;
    IOPACKAGE.OUTPUT_ARRAY(v_array);
  END;
END;
```

This is IOpackage sql file

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE IOpackage IS
  l_message VARCHAR2(100);
  PROCEDURE output_message(l_message IN VARCHAR2);
  TYPE number_array_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER(6, 2) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  PROCEDURE output_array(v_array NUMBER_ARRAY_TYPE);
END IOpackage;
```

and this is IOpackage_body file.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY IOpackage IS
  PROCEDURE output_message(l_message IN VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_message);
  END output_message;
  PROCEDURE output_array(v_array IN NUMBER_ARRAY_TYPE) IS
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..v_array.COUNT LOOP
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(v_array(i) || ' ');
            END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
  END output_array;
END IOpackage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type definition in *main sql file* is not the type that is expected by the package subroutine. `IOPACKAGE.OUTPUT_ARRAY`-subroutine expects type `IOPACKAGE.NUMBER_ARRAY_TYPE`. You don't have to re-define the type. The following should work:

```
declare
  v_array IOPACKAGE.NUMBER_ARRAY_TYPE;
begin
  IOPACKAGE.OUTPUT_ARRAY(v_array);
end;
```

See the difference between `IOPACKAGE.NUMBER_ARRAY_TYPE` and `NUMBER_ARRAY_TYPE`. They are similar but not the same.

Comment: I know this is quite an old answer but would you by any chance know how one could make the same call without specifying the precise "table" type? Is there a strategy one could employ which would allow for dynamic binding? I'm also thinking of syntactical, early bound type expressions (something like `%ROWTYPE`)

Comment: @EduardDumitru The design philosophy of PL/SQL inherited from ADA is that  (almost) everything is explicit, so the default answer is that you can't do that in with "pure" PL/SQL (assuming I guessed your "question" right). (I won't go in the rabbit hole of dynamic PL/SQL without details.) However maybe you can apply either [cursor variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00605) or [object types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjplsql.htm#ADOBJ070) to your problem ? If you think you have a genuine question then please ask it !