# type mismatch procedure arguments in varray plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am getting an error in the following code

```
create or replace package pkg
is
  TYPE ARRAY_TAB1 is VARRAY(120) OF VARCHAR2(30);
  ARRAY_TAB ARRAY_TAB1;
END;
/
show errors;
```

*error is somewhere in procedure arguments i think)*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FILTER_DATA(NESTED_TAB IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                        ARR_TAB IN OUT pkg.ARRAY_TAB%TYPE)
 IS
....
BEGIN
...
END;
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MAIN_PROC
 is
    NESTED_TAB VARCHAR2(30);
     TYPE ARRAY_TAB1 IS VARRAY(120) OF VARCHAR2(30);
     pass_array ARRAY_TAB1;
     .......
BEGIN
    NESTED_TAB := 'BOOKING';
    .......
    pass_array := new ARRAY_TAB1('');
    FILTER_DATA(NESTED_TAB,pass_array);
END;
/
EXEC MAIN_PROC()
```

***`I AM GETTING AN ERROR`*** WHICH MADE ME MAD.. PLEASE IF ANYBODY KNOWS THE SOLUTION

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

Errors for PROCEDURE MAIN_PROC:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
11/4     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
11/4     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
         'FILTER_DATA'

BEGIN MAIN_PROC(); END;

      *?
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object SYS.MAIN_PROC is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OUTPUT\_ARRAY'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759571/pls-00306-wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-output-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you declare in `main_proc` looks the same, but to the compiler is *not* the same as the one defined in the package and used in the declaration of `filter_data`. You have to use exactly the same types, not similar ones.

It should work if you just replace your new definition with package references:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MAIN_PROC
is
    NESTED_TAB VARCHAR2(30);
    pass_array pkg.ARRAY_TAB1;
    ...
BEGIN
    NESTED_TAB := 'BOOKING';
    .......
    pass_array := new pkg.ARRAY_TAB1(null);
    FILTER_DATA(NESTED_TAB,pass_array);
END;
/
```