# Passing TABLE type as parameter to PLSQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a plsql block like so that basically sets bunch of flags in a collection to run procedures in a package:

```
declare

  TYPE tRunFlagRec IS RECORD(tRunFlag BOOLEAN);
  TYPE tRunFlagTab IS TABLE OF tRunFlagRec INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);
  vValidationsTab tRunFlagTab;

begin

  vValidationsTab('some_validation_1').tRunFlag := true;
  vValidationsTab('some_validation_2').tRunFlag := true;
  vValidationsTab('some_validation_3').tRunFlag := true;
  vValidationsTab('some_validation_4').tRunFlag := true;

  owner.validation_pkg.main(pRunFlags => vValidationsTab);

end;
```

And a procedure with some if statements that calls other procedures based on the flags it receives:

```
  --declared in package
  TYPE tRunFlagRec IS RECORD(tRunFlag BOOLEAN);
  TYPE tRunFlagTab IS TABLE OF tRunFlagRec INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);
  vValidationsTab tRunFlagTab;

PROCEDURE MAIN(pRunFlags in tRunFlagTab) IS

    vSome_validation_1_FLAG  BOOLEAN := pRunFlags('FLAG_1').tRunFlag;
    vSome_validation_2_FLAG  BOOLEAN := pRunFlags('FLAG_2').tRunFlag;
    vSome_validation_3_FLAG  BOOLEAN := pRunFlags('FLAG_3').tRunFlag;
    vSome_validation_4_FLAG  BOOLEAN := pRunFlags('FLAG_4').tRunFlag;

  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checking for 1');
    IF vSome_validation_1_FLAG THEN
      GET_SOME_VALIDATION_1();
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Run Flag set to False. Skipping...');
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checking for 2');
    IF vSome_validation_2_FLAG THEN
      GET_SOME_VALIDATION_2();
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Run Flag set to False. Skipping...');
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checking for 3');
    IF vSome_validation_3_FLAG THEN
      GET_SOME_VALIDATION_3();
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Run Flag set to False. Skipping...');
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checking for 4');
    IF vSome_validation_4_FLAG THEN
      GET_SOME_VALIDATION_4();
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Run Flag set to False. Skipping...');
    END IF;
  END;
```

I'm getting the error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MAIN'. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OUTPUT\_ARRAY'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759571/pls-00306-wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-output-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't redeclare packaged types in local code.  The `tRunFlagRec` and `tRunFlagTab` types that you declare in your anonymous PL/SQL blocks are different than the types of similar names that are declared in the package so you can't use them interchangeably.  Just use the packaged types in your anonymous PL/SQL block

```
declare
  vValidationsTab owner.validation_pkg.tRunFlagTab;
begin
  vValidationsTab('some_validation_1').tRunFlag := true;
  vValidationsTab('some_validation_2').tRunFlag := true;
  vValidationsTab('some_validation_3').tRunFlag := true;
  vValidationsTab('some_validation_4').tRunFlag := true;

  owner.validation_pkg.main(pRunFlags => vValidationsTab);
end;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Relatively new to PLSQL. Makes perfect sense though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Create Package so that Declaration can be consistent for both caller and being called

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE declare_here
IS
   TYPE trunflagrec IS RECORD (
      trunflag   BOOLEAN
   );

   TYPE trunflagtab IS TABLE OF trunflagrec
      INDEX BY VARCHAR2 (64);
END;
```

Step 2 - This is where you are putting your logic, I have commented the some lines, but you can un-comment them in your code, they are straight forward

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE main (prunflags IN declare_here.trunflagtab)
IS
   vsome_validation_1_flag   BOOLEAN := prunflags ('some_validation_1').trunflag;
   vsome_validation_2_flag   BOOLEAN := prunflags ('some_validation_2').trunflag;
   vsome_validation_3_flag   BOOLEAN := prunflags ('some_validation_3').trunflag;
   vsome_validation_4_flag   BOOLEAN := prunflags ('some_validation_4').trunflag;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Checking for 1');

   IF vsome_validation_1_flag
   THEN
      --get_some_validation_1 ();
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('get_some_validation_1');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Run Flag set to False. Skipping...');
   END IF;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Checking for 2');

   IF vsome_validation_2_flag
   THEN
      --get_some_validation_2 ();
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('get_some_validation_2');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Run Flag set to False. Skipping...');
   END IF;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Checking for 3');

   IF vsome_validation_3_flag
   THEN
      --get_some_validation_3 ();
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('get_some_validation_3');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Run Flag set to False. Skipping...');
   END IF;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Checking for 4');

   IF vsome_validation_4_flag
   THEN
      --get_some_validation_4 ();
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('get_some_validation_4');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Run Flag set to False. Skipping...');
   END IF;
END;
```

Step 3 - Call the Procedure Created in Step 2

```
DECLARE
   vvalidationstab   declare_here.trunflagtab;
BEGIN
   vvalidationstab ('some_validation_1').trunflag := TRUE;
   vvalidationstab ('some_validation_2').trunflag := TRUE;
   vvalidationstab ('some_validation_3').trunflag := TRUE;
   vvalidationstab ('some_validation_4').trunflag := TRUE;
   main (prunflags => vvalidationstab);
END;
```